# Mongo::OperationFailure, Database command 'filemd5' failed: (errmsg: 'exception: best guess plan requested, but scan and order required)

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper, gridfs

I have an application that in uploading files to GridFS via MongoMapper/Joint in Padrino. Everything was working fine, and then all of a sudden, I'm getting the error:

```
Mongo::OperationFailure at /admin/wallpapers/create
Database command 'filemd5' failed: (errmsg: 'exception: best guess plan requested, but scan and order required: query: { files_id: ObjectId('4eaf4abf9972772c94000003') } order: { files_id: 1, n: 1 } choices: { $natural: 1 } '; code: '13284'; ok: '0.0').
```

The stack trace:

```
Mongo::OperationFailure - Database command 'filemd5' failed: (errmsg: 'exception: best guess plan requested, but scan and order required: query: { files_id: ObjectId('4eaf4c719972772c9400000b') } order: { files_id: 1, n: 1 } choices: { $natural: 1 } '; code: '13284'; ok: '0.0').:
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo-1.4.1/lib/mongo/db.rb:520:in `command'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo-1.4.1/lib/mongo/gridfs/grid_io.rb:463:in `get_md5'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo-1.4.1/lib/mongo/gridfs/grid_io.rb:453:in `to_mongo_object'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo-1.4.1/lib/mongo/gridfs/grid_io.rb:238:in `close'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo-1.4.1/lib/mongo/gridfs/grid.rb:73:in `put'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/joint-0.6.0/lib/joint/instance_methods.rb:22:in `block in save_attachments'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/joint-0.6.0/lib/joint/instance_methods.rb:18:in `each_pair'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/joint-0.6.0/lib/joint/instance_methods.rb:18:in `save_attachments'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_save_callbacks'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/activesupport-3.0.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/embedded_callbacks.rb:28:in `run_callbacks'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/callbacks.rb:14:in `create_or_update'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:143:in `save'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:20:in `block in save'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:42:in `clear_changes'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/dirty.rb:20:in `save'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/validations.rb:23:in `save'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:30:in `block in create'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:113:in `block in initialize_each'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:111:in `each'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:111:in `initialize_each'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.2/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:30:in `create'
 /var/www/fhsclock/admin/controllers/wallpapers.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:486:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:486:in `block in route'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:736:in `instance_eval'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:736:in `route_eval'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in process_destination_path'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:49:in `catch'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:49:in `block in process_destination_path'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:22:in `instance_eval'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:22:in `process_destination_path'
 (eval):16:in `block (2 levels) in inject_root_methods'
 (eval):6:in `catch'
 (eval):6:in `block in inject_root_methods'
 (eval):313:in `block in inject_root_methods'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/http_router-0.8.11/lib/http_router/node/root.rb:68:in `[]'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/http_router-0.8.11/lib/http_router.rb:110:in `block in call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/http_router-0.8.11/lib/http_router.rb:110:in `catch'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/http_router-0.8.11/lib/http_router.rb:110:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:796:in `route!'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/application/routing.rb:785:in `dispatch!'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:656:in `block in call!'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:820:in `block in invoke'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:820:in `catch'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:820:in `invoke'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:656:in `call!'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:641:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/rack-flash-0.1.2/lib/rack/flash.rb:147:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/reloader.rb:243:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/logger.rb:300:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:21:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:195:in `context'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:190:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:21:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1292:in `block in call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1323:in `synchronize'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/sinatra-1.2.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1292:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/router.rb:64:in `each'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/router.rb:64:in `call'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `block in pre_process'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `catch'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `pre_process'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/server.rb:44:in `start'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/server.rb:34:in `start'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/server.rb:13:in `run!'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/cli/adapter.rb:7:in `start'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:24:in `start'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/gems/padrino-core-0.10.0/bin/padrino:9:in `<top (required)>'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/bin/padrino:19:in `load'
 /home/ethan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@fhsclock/bin/padrino:19:in `<main>'
```

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/mongomapper/browse_thread/thread/6b6f71e77700708e) on the MongoMapper group suggests that I run `ensure_index` (or `create_index`) on the `files.chunk` collection. However, I do not know how to do this with MongoMapper.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I removed `:slave_ok => true` from my database configuration, everything worked fine. According the MongoDB docs, it shouldn't even use the slave. But, whatever works...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and as the author suggests, the line:

```
db.fs.chunks.ensureIndex({files_id: 1, n: 1})
```

Inside `mongo` console helped.

Full algorithm is that:

1. Open terminal, type `mongo`. Press enter.
2. Type `use <your database name>`. Press enter.
3. Type `db.fs.chunks.ensureIndex({files_id: 1, n: 1})`. Press enter.

Answer (score 0):

`YourClassName.ensureIndex(:files_id)`

Comment: If I apply that to the model with the Joint attachments, will it still ensure the index of `files.chunk`? Or just `YourClassName`?

Comment: I used `ensure_index` (`ensureIndex` is not a MongoMapper method), and 'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Could driver caching of indexes be part of the problem, per http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/25193

Answer (score 0):

Does the last answer in [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.db.mongodb.user/35550) help you out?

Comment: I'm not using a replica set, and I am still getting this issue.